# Does the usePreciseCollisionDetection property work when the physics body does not have a collisionBitMask

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I do not want my physics bodies to collide when they come in contact, but I want to use the 
`physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true` so that it detects contacts between the two bodies more accurately. So if I set

```
 physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None //Assume that PhysicsCategory is an Enum and .None means that the bit mask is set to 0 or nothing
 physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

Will the usesPreciseCollisionDetection still be valid? And if not, how to I implement more precise contact testing?
Thanks

Comment: Like hamobi said you don't have to use precise collision detection unless you don't have fast moving objects on the screen. You can try all this by yourself, but yeah, this works even if you "disable collisions" and just listen for contacts in didBeginContact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you usually need usesPreciseCollisionDetection to make sure that a fast moving object isnt passing through a set of tiles or other physics objects that are pressed together.  if youre just using the physics object as a sensor (just to test for collisions) then you probably dont need to use that.  I would guess that it works either way since the documentation doesnt say otherwise, but i dont think theres any way to know for sure..

EDIT:  It does matter..  if you want to detect fast moving objects set usesPreciseCollisionDetection to true.  You need it whether you have a collisionbitmask set or not.  Thanks Whirlwind!

Comment: "if youre just using the physics object as a sensor (just to test for collisions) then you probably dont need to use that." ... unless you want to register a contacts with a fast moving objects.

Comment: yeah im half guessing here as i havent tried registering physics contacts with anything going extremely fast.  probably easiest just to try it yourself and see if theres a difference.

Comment: I was lazy to test it when question came out, but finally I did it :) Speed of object matters. So if you move object toooo fast (but why would one do this?) there is a risk that contact (or collision) will go undetected (even with usesPreciseCollisionDetection =  true).

Comment: So if you forcefully set the collision bit mask to nothing, you can't use usesPreciseCollision right?